# dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: python

I have some data in my variable A :

```
A = [{'gestionnaire': "AAAAt", 'id': 'Affl.0', 'idObjet': 'BBB', 'nature': '03', 'precisione': '010'
    , 'producteur': "CCCC", 'qualiteCategorisation': '01', 'representation': {'href': 'GEOMETRIE.DDD'}, 'reseau': 'DECH', 'thematique
    e': '10}]
```

I can have some access of attribut like `id` and `producteur` for example.

```
for elem in A:
       print(elem['id'])
```

but if i want to acess to all data  it doesn't work :

```
for elem in A.values():
      print(elem)
```

Error :

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: This is not a dict object but an dict within a list

Comment: I was expecting your error to be: list has no attribute ‘values’

Comment: @quamrana yes my bad I just edited my post. It was another error.

Comment: Did you mean: for elem in A[0].values():  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like either dictionary inside a list or JSON. You can extract the dictionary out of the `A` then do your operations

```
A = [{'gestionnaire': "AAAAt", 'id': 'Affl.0', 'idObjet': 'BBB', 'nature': '03', 'precisione': '010'
    , 'producteur': "CCCC", 'qualiteCategorisation': '01', 'representation': {'href': 'GEOMETRIE.DDD'}, 'reseau': 'DECH', 'thematiquee': '10'}]

mydict = A[0]
for elem in mydict.values():
      print(elem)
```

Output:

```
AAAAt
Affl.0
BBB
03
010
CCCC
01
{'href': 'GEOMETRIE.DDD'}
DECH
10
```

In case it's JSON data you need to use

```
A = '''[{"gestionnaire": "AAAAt", "id": "Affl.0", "idObjet": "BBB", "nature": "03", "precisione": "010"
    , "producteur": "CCCC", "qualiteCategorisation": "01", "representation": {"href": "GEOMETRIE.DDD"}, "reseau": "DECH", "thematiquee": "10"}]'''

import json
x = json.loads(A)
print(x[0]['id'])
print(x[0]['idObjet'])
```

Output:

```
Affl.0
BBB
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your data structures.

If all are within a single level of list and not like dictionary within list within a dictionary tree. Then,

Use something like this.

```
A= [{'gestionnaire': "AAAAt", 'id': 'Affl.0', 'idObjet': 'BBB', 'nature': '03', 'precisione': '010'
    , 'producteur': "CCCC", 'qualiteCategorisation': '01', 'representation': {'href': 'GEOMETRIE.DDD'}, 'reseau': 'DECH', 'thematique': '10'}]
for list_item in A:
    if 'id' in list_item.keys():
             print(list_item['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will print all the values:

```
for x in A:
  for elem in x.keys():
      print(x[elem])
```

output :

```
AAAAt
Affl.0
BBB
03
010
CCCC
01
{'href': 'GEOMETRIE.DDD'}
DECH
10
```